# “D-module” or “$D$-module”?

Tags: notation, d-modules

**Disclaimer:** This question is not transcendental at all, so go easy on me.

Starting with a (for simplicity) commutative unital ring $R$, we define a $R$-module. Obviously, since the name of the ring was italicized, the same must be done each time we write “$R$-module”, but if we are talking about the *general* theory of modules over a ring, we simply write “module”.

On the other hand, given a ring $R$ of differential operators, we call a module over $R$ a **D-module** (“D” stands for “differential”, I guess$\ldots$). Of course, to denote the ring by $R$ in this situation is strange, so common sense dictates that we must use a “mathematical” variant of the letter D to denote such ring ($D,\mathscr{D},\mathcal{D}$, whatever$\ldots$). This subclass of modules is of great importance, so the corresponding theory has a name of its own: **D-module theory**, right?

> What is, then, the correct choice when we refer to the theory of modules over a ring of differential operators: “D-module theory” or “$D$-module theory”?

Comment: The italicizing just comes from how TeX typesets math. I say it doesn't matter.

Comment: @SeanRoberson We should be telling TeX how to typeset, not the other way around. There are good reasons why we can choose to write $\cos x$ instead of $cos \text{x}$. As for the $\text{D}$ (or $D$) in question, compare to $\int f(x)\ \text{d}x$ (as opposed to $\int f(x)dx$).

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con “put quotation marks correctly”? ¿Ponerlas dentro del código MathJax?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Yeah, I mean that. Note that quotation marks are incorrect at the title, and they appear "simple" at the body of the text. I want "66 -- 99" quotation marks.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas My keyboard has a special input to where I can type `“` and `”` manually as opposed to `"`. However, this is what MathJax produces: `“` $“$, `”` $”$, `"` $"$

Answer (score 0):

I am working with $D$-modules and I as you can see I am using the italic version. That is because it feels more natural to use the italic version as for other rings $R$ and $R$-modules. I am only working with one specific ring of differential operators though, which is the Weyl-Algebra $D = D_n$. So for me a $D$-module is really just a module over a specific ring and not a general module over some ring of differential operators, but I would also use the italic version in the latter case.